# PWA and FCM subscribe to a group

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Tried hard but couldn't get the push notification working for a FCM group.
USING this: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-push

But not sure this is the correct approach to use for FCM group in PWA 
Here is the curl and log

```
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/......./rel/topics/all2332
>> 
>> 
HTTP Error: 403 - Forbidden
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Forbidden</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Forbidden</H1>
<H2>Error 403</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

If you have an working example working with PWA (android).

Comment: I guess that Groups like Topic Based Subscriptions are something W3C refused to acknowledge the need for even though they were told at the time. They demand that the source of the push maintain the list of subscribers so that the  carrier never sees an unencrypted message.

Comment: But, i guess FCM was giving the api for sending message to a group. Is there any way to send messages to topic and PWA client get notified.